# OctoberCMS: How to extend a controller by adding or editing RelationController?

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

How can we extend a plugin by adding `Backend.Behaviors.RelationController` to one of its controllers? I need to extend the [User Plugin](https://github.com/rainlab/user-plugin) and add a `belongsToMany` relationship to its `User` model. I also want to extend its `Users` controller to implement the `Backend.Behaviors.RelationController` behavior. I know that form fields can be extended using `extendFormFields` and list columns can be extended using `extendListColumns`. But what about extending a plugin by adding or editing the [RelationController](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/relations#belongs-to-many) behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read up on the [Behavior documentation](https://octobercms.com/docs/services/behaviors#constructor-extension), specifically as it relates to extending classes to implement new behaviors.

Essentially, you will need to extend the Users controller to both implement the `RelationController` behavior and configure that behavior. A code example accomplishing that is below:

```
UsersController::extend(function($controller) {
    $controller->implement[] = ['Backend.Behaviors.RelationController'];
    $controller->relationConfig = '$/myvendor/myplugin/controllers/users/config_relation.yaml'
});
```